# How can I call a Java function from JavaScript in my Cordova/Phonegap application?

Tags: java, javascript, cordova

My application uses Cordova. I need to capture a keypress in my app and then call a Java function in my Cordova app, like so:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function() {
    // call mySpecialFunction() Java function here
});
```

and then the Cordova app's main activity:

```
public class EndPipe extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    }

    public void mySpecialFunction() {
        // some Java code here
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You will want to lookup `create cordova plugin` as you will need to build a cordova plugin to access native methods from JS.

Answer (score 7):

you can try this one

Firstly you need to declare your custom plugin in config.xml. You can found this file in res > xml folder.

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.Phonegap.CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Then you need to implement plugin by using Java- code

```
public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)
            throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("sayHello")){
            try {
                String responseText = "Hello world, " + args.getString(0);
                callbackContext.success(responseText);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                callbackContext.error("Failed to parse parameters");
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally we calling a plugin from javascript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```

Comment: Dato' Mohammad Nurdin may iknow where to put the java file on phonegap project?

Comment: Hi @LAnantaPrasad, from cordova you can execute `cordova plugin add MyPluginName` to create a stub plugin.